# Is there a term to refer to both page headers and page footers in desktop publishing?

Tags: print-design, page-layout, book, template-design

In desktop publishing, is there a single term to refer to both page headers and page footers?

(It's Ok if the term includes other elements, but it should exclude body text.)

Comment: I'm asking because I thought I had come across this before, but I forget.

Comment: Probably... Headers & Footers?

Comment: lol... given the good but slightly unconvincing responses so far (from my personal point of view), this might just be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Page Chrome** or **Document Chrome** *were* common terms. They were far more common before Google made a web browser. Now, searching for it you just get Google references. "Chrome" referred to common content across items/pages. This, may be why Google chose that particular name for their browser.

I've also seen it referred to as **Page Framing** or just **Framing** at times.

Both of these referred to what would be seen as "Parent Page" content.. running headers & footers, etc. Anything that was common on all, or most, pages.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I seem to remember this explanation from Google on how they named their browser...

Answer (score 0):

I personally refer to these as Universal design elements in my own work, because they should remain consistent throughout the entire site. But that's just what I personally use, and I'm unsure if there's any form of industry standard label for these types of elements.